# the size of the space and the char on the sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2

When I use the sublime in the default setting, the font is consolas, but the size of the space and the char is not the same[image]

In the picture, four space occupy two char size. Why?
When I change the font, there is no problem. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this problem is not sublime's problem and it is a font-related problem that is known and has a history about the history of computer science.

A monospaced font, also called a fixed-pitch, fixed-width or non-proportional font, is a font whose letters and characters each occupy the same amount of horizontal space. This contrasts with variable-width fonts, where the letters differ in size from one another.

I suggest that you read [Top 10 Programming Fonts](http://hivelogic.com/articles/top-10-programming-fonts) and [Wikipedia page about Monospaced font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font).

Then, after choosing your desired font to use in sublime, just change the default font to it, using [Font Settings](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/font.html).

Answer (score 0):

edit your Preferences.sublime-settings file.

location: preferences -> settings-user

{
    "font_face": "Courier",
    "font_size": 12
}